# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error on mac osx

Tags: c++, macos, eclipse-luna

I am currently studying classes in C++. I am using Eclipse Luna on a MAC OSX. I am unsure about this error message.[Snap of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zocty.png)
What could be causing the compilation error?

The code is simply designing a payment system for a juice dispenser.

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void disProduct (string);

int main ()
{
int choice;
string orange, apple, mango, strawberryBanana;

cout << "1 for orange juice \n"
     << "2 for apple juice \n"
     << "3 for mango juice \n"
     << "4 for strawberry-banana juice \n"
     << "9 to exit \n";

cin >> choice;

switch(choice)
{
    case 1:disProduct(orange);
            break;
    case 2:disProduct(apple);
            break;
    case 3:disProduct(mango);
            break;
    case 4:disProduct(strawberryBanana);
            break;
}

return 0;
}

void dispProduct (string name)
{
int vend;
cout << "please enter 50 cents";
cin >> vend;

while (vend > 0)
{
    if(vend < 50)
        {
        cout << "Please enter the remaining amount of " << 50-   vend;
        }

    if (vend >= 50)
        {
        cout << "please take your "<< name <<"juice and change
    << in the     amount of " << vend - 50;
        }
}

}
```

Comment: There should be a `default` option in in `switch-case` statement.

Comment: Curious, what is data type of `choice` ?

Comment: int type. Thanks for the default comment. I have fixed that. The issue still persists though.

Comment: shouldn't you `#include <string>` ? and do you have a console better than this terrible eclipse log that gives no info?

Comment: Thanks Jean. I have included the string library. That is the only information Luna gives me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declared function prototype is `void disProduct (string);` but the actual definition is `void dispProduct (string name)` and both the names are not same.

And also add `string` header too.